Syncing Cached Cloth Simulation with Geometry Nodes Animation
I currently have a simple scene of a few cubes individually moving right to a certain spot, animated using geometry nodes via their indexes. I also have a cached cloth sim of a curtain pulled to the right.

When I instance the cloth sim in the node setup, the animation is all synced:

Is there a way to start playing the cached animation for each instance the moment they start moving?
